# Listing files using Sh

Tags: bash, shell, unix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get the newest file based on timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495609/get-the-newest-file-based-on-timestamp)

I primary want to select latest dump file from specific folder so i can store in variable and use it import using import script

I want to list specific files from a specific, I tried:

```
a= $(ls -ltr /home/oracle/testora/MAUL01*.dmp | awk '{print $9}' | tail -1)
echo $a
```

I want output as:

```
MAUL01.DP.09-27-2012_09_15.dmp
```

instead of:

```
/home/oracle/testora/MAUL01.DP.09-27-2012_09_15.dmp
```

Problems:
ls is not working for me inside sh (working fine from unix)
file name is shown with path (I trid using basename, but cannot make it work)

Comment: Do you need this to be sh, as opposed to bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash, you can use the `${parameter##word}` syntax to remove everything before the last `/`.

You can also use `ls -tr1`, then you won't need `awk`.

This is shown below:

```
a=$(ls -tr1 /home/oracle/testora/MAUL01*.dmp | tail -1)
echo ${a##*/}
```

Comment: This is still evil. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 1):

Your code cannot work; there's a space after the `a=`. `basename` easily fixes this:

```
name="$(basename /home/oracle/testora/MAUL01*.dmp)" # Assumes only one glob match
echo "$name"
```

Also, [Use More Quotes™](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices/#Quoting) and [don't parse `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). If the issue is sorting the files, check [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/35797/3645):

```
IFS= read -r -d '' -u 9 9< <(find /home/oracle/testora/ -maxdepth 1 -name 'MAUL01*.dmp' -printf '%TY-%Tm-%TdT%TH:%TM:%TS %p\0' | sort -rz)
path="${REPLY#* }"
echo "$(basename "$path")"
```

Yes, handling filenames in Bash is hairy.

Comment: I'd use another parameter expansion to strip to the basename -- invoking a subshell (to run the basename command) and reading its output is needlessly inefficient. Otherwise, this is probably the best answer here.

Comment: Maybe if you're processing thousands of files. `for i in $(seq 1 1000); do foo=$(basename $PWD); done` takes about 1 second on my old Mac Mini. We're talking a single `basename` call in this case, so it's premature optimization (not to mention the common bug where a path ending with `/` is reduced to the empty string).

Comment: ...while I'm being nitpicky (eh, it's what we regulars in the Freenode #bash channel do) -- seq is a Linux-only thing; consider using a C-style for loop. `for ((i=1; i<1000; i++)); do ...`. As for the performance thing -- sure, it doesn't matter on modern hardware, but folks write scripts for routers and other embedded systems too.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go (no need basename there):

```
cd /home/oracle/testora
latest="$(ls -t MAUL01*.dmp | sed q)"
echo "The latest one is $latest $USER"
```

and with find :

```
cd /home/oracle/testora
latest="$(
    find -maxdepth 1 -name 'MAUL01*.dmp' -printf '%As %f\n' |
    sort -nk1 |
    tail -1
)"
```

Comment: `sed q` is a really obscure way to write `head -n 1`, though.

Comment: Yes, but much funny and shorter =)

Comment: This won't handle filenames with newlines correctly, even in the find version (find needs to be used with -print0 to safely distinguish the full range of legal UNIX filenames in its output).

Comment: @charles-duffy How do you know the OP has filenames with newlines? I don't know about you but I've never seen a filename with a newline! KISS and YAGNI!

Comment: I agree dogbane. Never seen any filename with newline in =~ 10 years.

Comment: @dogbane How do you know the OP doesn't? If you write code that breaks when confronted with valid but unexpected inputs, that's a great way to get security bugs. Think having attackers deliberately creating files with the form `/tmp/$'\n'/etc/passwd`.

Comment: I have no problem with archlinux and newlines in filename : http://sputnick-area.net/pasteme/345

Comment: @sputnick That _is_ a problem -- you're getting something back that isn't a valid filename, so you have a file you couldn't delete by, say, sending the output from find into `rm`. Granted, it isn't rendered as a literal newline with your version of find and that distribution, but if you were using, say, find's `-printf`, you'd be getting different results.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
a=$(ls -ltr /home/oracle/testora/MAUL01*.dmp | awk '{print $9}' | tail -1)
echo $(basename $a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Easily (and safely) done with parameter expansion; no need for either ls (which is dangerous and behaves differently between operating systems) or find (which is also dangerous unless used with -print0 and some tricks to process a NUL-delimited stream). This is the POSIX sh compatible version:

```
set -- /home/oracle/testora/MAUL01*.dmp
for filename; do
  echo "${filename##*/}"
done
```

If you're using bash instead, you can store your glob's output in an array, and thus not override `$@`:

```
shopt -s nullglob
filenames=( /home/oracle/testora/MAUL01*.dmp )
for filename in "${filenames[@]}"; do
  echo "${filename##*/}"
done
```

If you want to filter for only the most recent file, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003