# Finding when node packages were last updated

Tags: node.js, npm

Between now and a couple of days ago, one of the node dependencies my project relies on has updated and now my test suite fails. I would expect this to have been a patch or minor update given I haven't touched my code let alone package.json in the meantime. Have fell foul of NPM's default install mode.

Is there a way to list the timestamp that the currently installed version of all my dependencies (and presumably, the sub-dependencies too) was updated, so that I can work out what's changed since the last known good version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the newest file based on timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495609/get-the-newest-file-based-on-timestamp)

Comment: I think just getting the newest files would exactly tell you what and when was updated

Comment: Hey -- I get your point but not quite what looking for here. `node_modules` has been wiped so everything in there has the same timestamps. Need to get more forensic...

Comment: ok, then looks like you need to search for the NPM logs somehow...

Comment: Resolved by changing all my '^1.2.3' style dependencies to fixed '1.2.3' ones. Was a patch update from React Native's babel transform.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by changing all my '^1.2.3' style dependencies to fixed '1.2.3' ones. Was a patch update from React Native's babel transform.